# Encoding error - xlsxwriter - Python

Tags: python, excel, encoding, utf-8, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to split lines from a file and put them into a excel file (xlsx). According to PS PAD, encoding of the file is 'cp1250'. So to have proper characters in xlsx file, I'm decoding this lines from cp1250 - `line = line.decode("cp1250")`

The problem is that cca 3000 lines from 12000 returns this error:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

So as next thing I tried to decode("utf-8"), I don't know why, but it's better. There are only 330 lines which return error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Have you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT: Errors are mostly occured when line contains 'Ž' or 'Š'**

Here is the code: (on the top of the py file I've put "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-")

```
def toXls(file):
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
a=0
with open("filtrovane.txt") as f:
    x=0
    for line in f:

        try:
            line = line[:-1].decode("utf-8") """It should be "cp1250" according to PSPAD editor"""
            # line = line.encode("ISO 8859-2")
            splitted = line.split("::")

            if len(splitted)==7:
                try:
                    a=a+1
                    worksheet.write(a,0,splitted[0])
                    worksheet.write(a,1,splitted[1])
                    worksheet.write(a,2,splitted[2])
                    worksheet.write(a,3,splitted[3])
                    worksheet.write(a,4,splitted[4])
                    worksheet.write(a,5,splitted[5])
                    worksheet.write(a,6,splitted[6])
                except Exception as e:
                    print "!!"+line+" "+a + e
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            x=x+1
print x
workbook.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you try to save it to a text file, does the same issue occur?

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples in the XlsxWriter docs/repo that show how to read [UTF-8](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_unicode_polish_utf8.html) and [Shift JIS](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_unicode_shift_jis.html) files and convert them to xlsx files.

It should work the same for `cp1250`.